# Applescript for batch-converting text delimited .txt to .xls

Tags: applescript, delimiter, automator

Each day, I'm delivered ~5 .txt data files delimited with "^". Manual steps taken to convert each to spreadsheet:
• Open .txt file in Excel
• Text-To-Columns
• Run through the delimiting wizard

Would love to have an applescript or applet to drop the 5 files into. A Google Sheets script would be even more magical. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

**Sample data:**

```
developer^project^lender^uuid^id^remarks^code^transfer_date
1500^1502^009^f1e97d20-b311-41cf-a40f-59db90b25ba8^73890^a10a46e8-bca8-4f0d-8938-8f2803a8bf90^9^2018-10-23 10:17:23.0
1500^1502^009^5dfc330d-0b9a-407d-a9e6-36895207b89e^74460^4a9c046a-a544-45b5-a627-f567b94f2b87^9^2018-10-23 10:17:25.0
1500^1502^009^d3295a4a-235d-4b9d-8775-5c079571193e^74901^de8f7b66-0c14-450f-8f29-c30c9a8329fa^9^2018-10-23 10:17:26.0
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample of one of your `.txt` files ?  Please format it using a code block so that the character-spacing is preserved.  To do this, highlight a selection of text that you'd like to format, and press the `{}` button in the toolbar of the editing pane.  Alternatively, enclose the text inside the tags `<pre>...</pre>`.

Comment: Thanks, CJK. Here you go:

Comment: <pre>developer^project^lender^uuid^id^remarks^code^transfer_date
1500^1502^009^f1e97d20-b311-41cf-a40f-59db90b25ba8^73890^a10a46e8-bca8-4f0d-8938-8f2803a8bf90^9^2018-10-23 10:17:23.0
1500^1502^009^5dfc330d-0b9a-407d-a9e6-36895207b89e^74460^4a9c046a-a544-45b5-a627-f567b94f2b87^9^2018-10-23 10:17:25.0
1500^1502^009^d3295a4a-235d-4b9d-8775-5c079571193e^74901^de8f7b66-0c14-450f-8f29-c30c9a8329fa^9^2018-10-23 10:17:26.0</pre>

Comment: So you basically get 5 text files like the one above and you want to make xls versions of them?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the file paths supplied at the start of the script inside the variable `CSVFiles`. The *Excel* file is saved in the same directory as the CSV file from which it sources its data, and uses the same filename, appending the extension `".xlsx"` to it.

```
use Excel : application "Microsoft Excel"
use scripting additions

# Used to split the CSV data into columns
property text item delimiters : {"/", "^"}

# These represent the 5 CSV files you are sent on a given day
set CSVFiles to {¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample.csv", ¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample2.csv", ¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample3.csv", ¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample4.csv", ¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample5.csv"}

repeat with fp in CSVFiles
    try
        # Make sure CSV file exists
        fp as POSIX file as alias
    on error
        false
    end try
    set f to the result

    if f ≠ false then
        # Obtain directory and filename to use for saving Excel document
        set [dirpath, filename] to [¬
            text items 1 thru -2 of POSIX path of f as text, ¬
            text item -1 of POSIX path of f]

        # Read the CSV data into an array (list)
        set CSVrows to paragraphs of (read f)
        if the last item of CSVrows = "" then ¬
            set CSVrows to items 1 thru -2 of CSVrows

        repeat with r in CSVrows
            set r's contents to text items of r
        end repeat

        set n to count CSVrows
        set cellrange to "A1:H" & n
        set colHrange to "H2:H" & n

        # Create the Excel sheet
        make Excel new document
        set S to active sheet of window 1 of Excel
        # Copy in CSV data
        set value of range cellrange to CSVrows
        # Format the last column to handle dates & times
        set number format of range colHrange to "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

        # Save & Close
        save S in (dirpath & "/" & filename & ".xlsx")
        Excel's (close front window)
    end if
end repeat
```

If you had a dedicated folder into which you saved your newly received CSV files, then this line:

```
set CSVFiles to {¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample.csv", ¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample2.csv", ¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample3.csv", ¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample4.csv", ¬
    "/Users/CK/Desktop/sample5.csv"}
```

could be replaced with this line:

```
tell app "System Events" to set CSVFiles to the POSIX path of ¬
    every file in the folder named "/Path/To/Folder for CSV files" whose ¬
    name extension = "CSV"
```

Then, all you'd need to do is remove yesterday's CSV files from that directory (you don't want them being processed a second time); transfer in today's CSV files; then execute the script.

Alternatively, as you stated in your question, you can create an applet onto which CSV files can be dropped and processed.  This would be done via *Automator*.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @CJK!

Comment: @earshot, if you're satisfied with my answer, could you mark it as the selected answer? It helps other users find their way here, helps the community to know a question has been solved, and helps me gain good standing.