# Read Values from Excel Worksheet on Mac

Tags: excel, macos

I am on Mac OSX El Capitan. My goal is to retrieve values given the parameters of the filename, the worksheetname (or worksheet number), the column name (or column number) and some kind of key.

The ability to use a SQL like syntax to create joins would be much appreciated on top of that.

To be clear: I don't want to query databases from Excel. I want to read Excel data from the outside (and possibly change some cells values later on)

I know it is possible on Windows with ADODB, but that isn't applicable to the Mac.

I am happy to use Apple Script, shell script, powershell or any other language you throw at me :-) Which options do I have short of traversing the sheets on a cell by cell basis?

Comment: AppleScript seems to be able to talk to Excel: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8345854

Comment: There are some useful techniques here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997934/2836621

Comment: ... and Python can also access `.xlsx` files too https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thanks, I had seen this before. But that is what I meant by scripting it myself. That is very low level and I‘d have to traverse the cell themselves. I‘ll update the question

Comment: Or you could import `.xlsx` into **sqlite** which ships with macOS anyway https://sqlitebiter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/usage/file/

Comment: OpenPyXl I had not seen, but for doing the low level implementation it looks much better than Apple Script

Comment: SQLite... now we are talking. Will check that out and report

Comment: I noticed, that I value the flexibility of the scripting approach a lot. I don't want to necessarily change the excel, save it, import it into SQLite and then work from there, but work on a live workbook. So I am opting for the scripting approach now. I was about to use OpenPyXl as suggested, but it turns out, that my Python environment is somehow messed up. So I'll try my hands on Apple scripting it. Thanks everyone :-)